# Cannot pass parameter to httpLBS in Network.HTTP.Simple

Tags: haskell, request, httpclient

I can't figure out why the following code works:

```
main = do
    response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get"
    let statusCode = show $ getResponseStatusCode response
    putStrLn statusCode
```

But this does not:

```
getStatusCode url = do
 response <- httpLBS url
 let statusCode = show $ getResponseStatusCode response
 putStrLn statusCode
```

When called like `getStatusCode "http://httpbin.org/get"` I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:38:15: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Request' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the first argument of `getStatusCode', namely
        `"http://httpbin.org/get"'
      In the expression: getStatusCode "http://httpbin.org/get"
      In an equation for `it':
          it = getStatusCode "http://httpbin.org/get"
```

The error message seems to imply that httpLBS needs a Request type. But I can't figure out why the first one works in that case.

Comment: the error is pretty straightforward, you are passing a `String` or `[Char]` as parameter, but he wants a `Request`, probably you need to build that

Comment: Are you using `OverloadedStrings`?

Comment: Is it possible that `httpLBS` is not the same as [`httpLbs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.7.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:httpLbs)?

Comment: @Daenyth yes I do have OverloadedStrings active. Should have mentioned that, apologies. Here is the full file https://github.com/thomasdane/haskellApi/blob/master/src/Main.hs

Comment: Just to drop in the solution via your gist: https://gist.github.com/FintanH/84d4b50c52646f1c82a8ea79afc327fe

Comment: @FintanH I think your solution is tricky, here I would prefer to use `parseRequest`. Or at least add type signatures and rename `url` to `request`